# Request mapping in Spring boot with url-encoded characters

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

In my Spring Boot application I have an URL concatenated from values that go from client side, for example:

> /api/foo/{client-defined-value}/bar/

and the real URL can be something like this:

> /api/foo/OBCH.%20Z%C3%81STUPCI/bar/

(not url encoded value is "OBCH. ZÁSTUPCI")

In a controller I have definition of GET request mapping:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/foo/{value:[^\\/]+}/bar/")
```

but the mapping is not found:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You can acces the URL variable by using the annotation `@Pathvariable("client-defined-value")` as a method argument.

Like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/foo/{client-defined-value}/bar/")
public void foo(@PathVariable("client-defined-value") String value) {
    doSomething…
}
```

Comment: Read my question, please. There is an issue with HTTP request mapping to a particular controller method, not with a reading a value from URL as you understood.

Comment: Change your requestmapping to @RequestMapping(value = "/api/foo/{client-defined-value}/bar/") ? Doesn't this help?